# Yii2 disable debug log for specific controller/action

Tags: debugging, yii2

In general in development mode i have to use the debug and logging for bugtracing.

But on a specific controller/action i don't want this to happen since it's just a background ajax that gets called every 2 seconds, which ends ups in a huge amount of "unneeded" logs.

How can I exclude this specific call "site/ajaxupdate" from being logged?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simply disable the corresponding log target in your controller, e.g. :

```
\Yii::$app->log->targets['file']->enabled = false;
```

Read more about [toggling log targets](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-logging.html#toggling-log-targets).

Answer (score 1):

YII 2 it may be accomplished by:

```php
foreach (\Yii::$app->log->targets as $target) {
    $target->setEnabled(false);
}
```